# Mysql get tuples where date is from this month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've written this SQL query but it's returning null although it shouldn't

I'm working with a db containing work times. So each work times has a beginning datetime and an end datetime

I'd like to get all the work times that have been recorded this month :

```
        SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(DATE(t.begin), "%d-%m-%Y") as date,
          CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(t.begin, "%H:%i"), " - ", DATE_FORMAT(t.end, "%H:%i")) as timerange,
          CASE WHEN t.end = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
            THEN TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), t.begin), "%H:%i")
            ELSE TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(t.end, t.begin), "%H:%i") 
          END as fulltime_duration,
          (
            SELECT TIMEDIFF(l.end, l.begin) as duration
            FROM timeslots l
            WHERE l.type = 2
            AND l.parent_id = t.id
          ) as lunch_duration

        FROM timeslots t
        WHERE t.user_id = '.$userId.'
        AND t.approved = 1
        AND t.type = '.Timeslot::DAY.'
        AND DATE(begin) >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m-01")
        ORDER BY t.begin
```

when I replace this line :

```
AND DATE(begin) >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m-01")
```

by :

```
AND WEEKOFYEAR(begin) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
```

it returns all the times recorded this week. So everything is working except this line

```
AND DATE(begin) >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m-01")
```

When I replace the "-01" by "%d" it returns all the work times of today so **I guess the problem comes from this "-01"**. But I don't see how to do this in a different way.

Anyone to help me ?...

Comment: try : AND DATE(begin) >= DATE(CURDATE())

Comment: Your condition works for me: http://rextester.com/HEBEM85257

Comment: @ShankaSMS this is returning the time slots of today, which is logic

Comment: no one to help me ?...

Comment: I tried this, but it still returned an empty result : AND DATE_FORMAT(t.begin, "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y-%m")

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
    DATE(begin) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), 1 - DAY(CURDATE()))
```

Note:  You don't need `DATE(begin)` (because the time component will make this bigger), so you can use:

```
    begin >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), 1 - DAY(CURDATE()))
```

The advantage is that this can make use of an index on `begin`, if appropriate.

Comment: It returned this error : check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 - DAY(CURDATE()))

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us the version?

Comment: Server version: 5.5.45-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL) / 
Protocol version: 10 / PHP version: 5.6.23 / Version information: 4.5.2

Comment: @FabulousCo . . . This syntax should work in MySQL 5.5.